# Python for loop for items with the same id

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am still very new to Python and I am trying to learn. I tried looking for a similar question but I was unable to find an answer to my question. Basicaly, I have a psql datatable with 3 columns in it as shown on the picture down below, one of the columns is a text column which saves comments people left, one of them is the id of each comment and the last one is the id of which account they are linked to. My question is, how can i print all of the texts that have msr.id equal to 72 knowing that there are multiple texts with msr_id equal to 72 (how can i print all of the comments of one single user who's msr_id is equal to 72)? Here's my Python code:

```
class Commentaire(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "commentaire"

    msr_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    text = db.Column(db.Text())
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    def __init__(self, text, msr_id):
        self.text = text
        self.msr_id = msr_id

@app.route("/msr/<int:item_id>/history")
@require_privilege()
@templated("MSR/history.htm")
def msr_history(item_id=None):
    msr = MSR.query.get(item_id)
    commentaire = Commentaire.query.get(item_id) <--- this is the table in my database
    print(msr.pos)
    while (commentaire.id < 74):
        if (commentaire.msr_id == 72):
            print(commentaire.text)
        commentaire.id += 1
    if msr is None:
        return abort(404)
    return {"msr": msr, "first_pos": str(), "commentaire": commentaire}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use the WHERE clause to restrict the output. Something like `SELECT text, id, msr_id from the_table WHERE msr_id=72`

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your question. This is because I am not doing it in a terminal but in my python code. I just use query.get.

Comment: I think you need to use ```filter()``` instead of ```get()``` to get all the matching rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an `if` and not a `while` since you want to print only the comments that has 72 as id.

```
def msr_history(item_id=None):
    msr = MSR.query.get(item_id)
    commentaire = Commentaire.query.get(item_id) database
    print(msr.pos)
    
    # Not sure if it works. I am assuming commentaire returns a queryset. 
    for item in commentaire:
        if (item.msr_id == 72) 
            print(commentaire.text) 


    if msr is None:
        return abort(404)
    return {"msr": msr, "first_pos": str(), "commentaire": commentaire}
```

Comment: the problem is that now it only prints the very first comment with msr_id equal to 72 once and not the other comments

Comment: You need to add that ```if ``` inside a loop. I don't know what ```commentaire``` looks like. So I haven't included it.

Comment: oh sorry I didn't see that, thanks I'll try it right now by doing a loop with commentaire.id!

Comment: I guess commentaire returns a queryset. I have added a loop in my code. You may please check if that works.

Comment: I have just updated my question with the loop i tried but when i try to run this I am getting this error: sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError: UPDATE statement on table 'commentaire' expected to update 1 row(s); 22 were matched. and there are indeed 22 comments with the msr_id equal to 72 but I don't know why I am getting this error

Comment: Did you try what I have added in my code. I have used a ```for-loop``` considering commentaire is a queryset. Please check if that works. *I have no  idea of SQLalchemy*

Comment: Yes, I have just tried what you added but when i do this i get this error:     for item in commentaire:
TypeError: 'Commentaire' object is not iterable

Comment: Could you post what ```Commentaire``` looks like.

Comment: Yes of course! I will add it to my original post.

Comment: I think you need to use ```filter()``` instead of ```get()``` to get all the matching rows and then use a ```for-loop``` what I have used in my code.

Comment: I honestly did not even know there was a filter option, I xill try this tomorrow, thanks!!